# Does OCaml have String.split function like Python?

Tags: split, ocaml, string-parsing

I am using this to split strings:

```
 let split = Str.split (Str.regexp_string " ") in
   let tokens = split instr in
 ....
```

But the problem is that for example here is a sentence I want to parse:

```
pop     esi
```

and after the split it turns to be (I use a helper function to print each item in the `tokens` list):

```
item: popitem: item: item: item: esi
```

See, there are **three spaces** in the token list.

I am wondering if there is a `string.split` like in Python which can parse `instr` this way:

```
item: popitem: esi
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Don't use `Str.regexp_string`, it's only for matching fixed strings.

Use `Str.split (Str.regexp " +")`

Answer (score 9):

Since OCaml 4.04.0 there is also `String.split_on_char`, which you can combine with `List.filter` to remove empty strings:

```
# "pop     esi"
  |> String.split_on_char ' '
  |> List.filter (fun s -> s <> "");;
- : string list = ["pop"; "esi"]
```

No external libraries required.

Answer (score 7):

Using [Jane Street's Core library](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/111.28.00/doc/core/#Core_string), you can do:

```
let python_split x =
  String.split_on_chars ~on:[ ' ' ; '\t' ; '\n' ; '\r' ] x
  |> List.filter ~f:(fun x -> x <> "")
;;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I split my lines into words:

```
open Core.Std
let tokenize line = String.split line ~on: ' ' |> List.dedup
```

Mind the single quotes around the space character.

Here's the documentation for `String.split`: [link](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/109.08.00/doc/core/String.html#VALsplit)