# Not able to get a module function working

Tags: string, ocaml

I am trying this simple code to split a string to a list by a separator:

```
open String;;
let ss = "/usr/bin/ocaml";;
let sslist = String.split_on_char '/' ss  in
    print_endline sslist;;
```

It is giving error:

```
$ ocaml testing.ml

File "testing.ml", line 5, characters 13-33:
Error: Unbound value String.split_on_char
```

I am sure it is something very basic but I am not able to solve it. Removing `open String` or using `#require "string"` also does not work.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does `ocaml -version` say? `String.split_on_char` is only available since 4.04.0, as per the docs.

Comment: My version is `The OCaml toplevel, version 4.02.3`. So that explains. How can I split a string in my version?

Comment: You could use `Str.split`, or something in a stdlib replacement like Base/Core, I'm sure. But you really should upgrade. 4.02.3 is pretty old, we'll soon be on 4.08 now.

Comment: I have installed from Debian Stable repositories.

Comment: I would recommend using opam instead to manage both your ocaml installations and third-party packages. [It's also available in the Debian repos](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.split_on_char` is only available since 4.04.0, as per the docs.

You really should upgrade, but in case you can't, [refer to this question for alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23204953/7943564).